# how to transform a DataFrame into a Dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following dataframe:

```
    Group SubGroup
0  GroupA       A1
1  GroupA       A2
2  GroupA       A3
3  GroupB       B1
4  GroupB       B2
5  GroupC       C1
```

How do I transform this Dataframe in a dictionary?
My expected output is as follows:

```
{'GroupA': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], 'GroupB': ['B1', 'B2'], 'GroupC': ['C1']}
```

Comment: Please include a script that initializes the dataframe so that answers can be tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `groupby` and then `to_dict` function:

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'group':['A','A','A','B','B','C'], 'subgrroup':['A1','A2','A3','B1','B2','C1']})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
  group subgrroup
0     A        A1
1     A        A2
2     A        A3
3     B        B1
4     B        B2
5     C        C1

In [5]: df2 = df.groupby('group')['subgrroup'].apply(list)

In [6]: df2
Out[6]: 
group
A    [A1, A2, A3]
B        [B1, B2]
C            [C1]
Name: subgrroup, dtype: object

In [7]: df2.to_dict()
Out[7]: {'A': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], 'B': ['B1', 'B2'], 'C': ['C1']}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby('Group')['SubGroup'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `pd.DataFrameGroupBy.keys` with a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> {k: df.loc[v, 'SubGroup'].tolist() for k, v in df.groupby('Group').groups.items()}
{'GroupA': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], 'GroupB': ['B1', 'B2'], 'GroupC': ['C1']}
>>>
```

Or try `pd.SeriesGroupBy.agg`:

```
>>> dict(df.groupby('Group')['SubGroup'].agg(list))
{'GroupA': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], 'GroupB': ['B1', 'B2'], 'GroupC': ['C1']}
>>>
```

Even better with `to_dict`:

```
>>> df.groupby('Group')['SubGroup'].agg(list).to_dict()
{'GroupA': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], 'GroupB': ['B1', 'B2'], 'GroupC': ['C1']}
>>>
```